# Replace values based on matching REGEX with another column r tidy

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, stringr

I would like to replace values of a dataset with corrected values if those corrected are not NA.

```
df <- tibble(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  name = c("peter", "piper", "paul"),
  alex.value = c("apple","banana","apple"),
  alex.corrected = c("orange",NA,"banana"),
  bob.value = c("monkey","lion","tiger"),
  bob.corrected = c("lion","tiger", NA)
)
```

Desired output

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    alex = if_else(!is.na(alex.corrected), alex.corrected,
                                      alex.value),
    bob = if_else(!is.na(bob.corrected), bob.corrected,
                                      bob.value),
  )
```

I need to do this for many columns, so it would be great to have a solution that scales.
I'm thinking it will involve REGEX and maybe purrr, something like

```
df %>%
map_df( str_detect(unique(*\\.)
```

but that is just a wild guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` to split the column names at the delimiter `.`, then `transmute` by `coalesce`ing the 'corrected' with 'value', reshape back to 'wide' format and bind with the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
   select(matches("value|corrected"))  %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_sep="\\.",
          names_to = c("grp", '.value')) %>%
   transmute(grp, value = coalesce(corrected, value))%>% 
   mutate(rn = rowid(grp)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = value) %>% 
   select(-rn) %>% 
   bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#     id name  alex.value alex.corrected bob.value bob.corrected alex   bob  
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <chr>          <chr>     <chr>         <chr>  <chr>
#1     1 peter apple      orange         monkey    lion          orange lion 
#2     2 piper banana     <NA>           lion      tiger         banana tiger
#3     3 paul  apple      banana         tiger     <NA>          banana tiger
```

---

Or in `base R` with `split.default`

```
nm1 <- grep('value|corrected', names(df), value = TRUE)
cbind(df, lapply(split.default(df[nm1], sub("\\..*", "", nm1)), 
          function(x)  ifelse(is.na(x[[2]]), x[[1]], x[[2]])))
#  id  name alex.value alex.corrected bob.value bob.corrected   alex   bob
#1  1 peter      apple         orange    monkey          lion orange  lion
#2  2 piper     banana           <NA>      lion         tiger banana tiger
#3  3  paul      apple         banana     tiger          <NA> banana tiger
```

Comment: Thank you! I have one additional part my question, which I'll edit now. There are some values that are not meant to be changed (e.g., id, name, etc.).

Comment: @Nick In that case, just subset the data with only the columns that need to be changed i.e. `df %>% select(matches("value|corrected")) %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything(), ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the data by their column names and use the same logic as in your attempt with `Map` :

```
value_cols <- grep('value', names(df), value = TRUE)
corrected_cols <- grep('corrected', names(df), value = TRUE)
new_cols <- sub('\\..*', '', value_cols)

df[new_cols] <- Map(function(x, y) ifelse(!is.na(x), x, y), 
                    df[corrected_cols], df[value_cols])
```

If you prefer a `tidyverse` solution :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
  bind_cols(map2_df(df[corrected_cols], df[value_cols], coalesce) %>%
  rename_with(~new_cols))
  #In old dplyr use rename_all
  #rename_all(~new_cols))


# A tibble: 3 x 8
#     id name  alex.value alex.corrected bob.value bob.corrected alex   bob  
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <chr>          <chr>     <chr>         <chr>  <chr>
#1     1 peter apple      orange         monkey    lion          orange lion 
#2     2 piper banana     NA             lion      tiger         banana tiger
#3     3 paul  apple      banana         tiger     NA            banana tiger
```

Comment: I'm interested in this solution, because I'd like to perform the function only on subset of the dataframe while maintaining the entire dataframe. E.g. `df %>% filter(id %in% c("1","3")) %>%`... How could I do this?

Comment: @Nick `newdf <- df %>% filter(id %in% c("1","3"))` and then use the above solution with `newdf` ?

Comment: OK this is helpful. I split the dataframe into two then did `bind_rows` to join them again